# Dummy variables in SKLearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

General question. When creating a data set, thusfar I always changed categorical feautures to numbers myself.

For example: 5 categories for a single feature result in 1 feature with numbers 1,2,3,4,5.

Creating dummy variables in Pandas results in several features with 0 or 1 values. Is the latter a best practice, or is it just a matter of taste? In my model, this does not affect the accuracy, so trial and error does not provide an answer in this situation.

Comment: [Relevant question on CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115049/why-do-we-need-to-dummy-code-categorical-variables) (which is actually the preferred place for such a question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the data that you are trying to convert. If it is oridinal data like say `slow`,`medium` and `fast`, then it makes sense sense to convert them to numbers like `1,2 and 3`. This is because they seem to have some sort of order and sequence. However, if you have data like city names, you cannot use this method, because it will unnecessarily create a relationship of sequence between the cities which might not be the case.

For example if you do the following mapping :

```
"New York" - 1
"London"   - 2
"Moscow"   - 3
"Beijing"  - 4
```

Then you introduce a new relationship between the different cities, like suppose `New York` has less value than `London`, etc. This is because the ML algorithms will treats Numbers as sequences and their ordering is important( which is not true for the names of cities). Hence it depends upon your data and how you encode it.

You can check for more encoding techniques in [this blog post](http://www.kdnuggets.com/2015/12/beyond-one-hot-exploration-categorical-variables.html) as well.